# apt: E: Couldn't find any package

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm having some problem on my Kali Linux 2016.2, I can't install any package on my machine. it says every time

```
E: Unable to locate package libasound2-plugins_1.0.28-1+b1_i386.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libasound2-plugins_1.0.28-1+b1_i386.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libasound2-plugins_1.0.28-1+b1_i386.deb'
```

I tried to fix repository issue by `leafpad /etc/apt/sources.list`, sources get from docs.kali.org , it says while updating repository

```
N: Ignoring file 'some-ppa.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

but there are no any file in  `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
#The Kali Rolling Repository 

deb repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free 
# deb-src repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m guessing you’re running

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins_1.0.28-1+b1_i386.deb
```

That won’t work on Kali Linux; if you’ve already downloaded the package, you need to run

```
sudo dpkg -i libasound2-plugins_1.0.28-1+b1_i386.deb
```

instead, and if you haven’t, just run

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins
```

`apt-get` works on package names, not complete package filenames.

Note that `sudo dpkg -i` won’t deal with missing dependencies, so you’re probably better off using `apt-get` anyway. (Alternatively, install `gdebi` and use that, but you might as well just stick to `apt-get`.)

Answer (score 0):

try sudo apt install & sudo apt update, then restarting your computer if that doesn't work try re installing Linux.

Comment: Re-installing seems a bit drastic